# Is there a way to remove optgroup without destroying the code?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

All I was attempting was to edit some old code, where I had made an option group, but now I'd like to take it away. I can't just do it with css because it's using the chosen plugin.

```
function flavorChooser (title, item) {
var title = 'hidden';
var optgroup = jQuery('<optgroup display="' + title + '"/>');


jQuery.each(item, function(sub_title, sub_item) {
    if (typeof sub_item[0] !== "undefined") {
        var opt = jQuery('<option value="' + sub_item[0] + '" data-store-locator-value="' + sub_item[0] + '">' + sub_title + '</option>');
        optgroup.prepend(opt);
    }
});
// console.log('chozen ');
// jQuery('.chzn-container .chzn-results .group-result').css('display', 'none');
return optgroup;
```

}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works to remove all of the `optgroup` children of a given `select` element:

Markup:

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <optgroup label="MyGroup"></optgroup>
    <option>Option</option>
    <option>Option</option>
    <option>Option</option>
    <option>Option</option>
    <optgroup label="MyGroup2"></optgroup>
    <option>Option</option>
    <option>Option</option>
    <option>Option</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
 $(function () {
        $("#mySelect").children().remove("optgroup");
    });
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/frJEq/

Comment: Why are the options not nested inside the optgroups?

Comment: @Moeri, because that is what that jquery code accomplishes, it removes the optgroup.

Answer (score 4):

This is how to find it from label and remove,

```
$("#mySelect").children().remove("optgroup[label='MyGroup']");
```

p.s this is what I wanted and publishing for others benefit

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#mySelect").children().remove('optgroup[label=MyGroup2]');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
 <optgroup label="MyGroup">
  <option>Option1</option>
  <option>Option2</option>
  <option>Option3</option>
  <option>Option4</option>
 </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="MyGroup2">
  <option>Option5</option>
  <option>Option6</option>
  <option>Option7</option>
 </optgroup>
</select>
```