# Laravel dropdown without optgroup

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-4

I decided to try out Laravel and wanted to create dropdowns for my form. I created a convinience method inside my BaseController that I use to get the data from the database. Below is the function listing:

```
protected function getList( $model, array $fields, $empty = 'Select option  below' )
{
    $options = array();

    $owner = strtolower( $model ) . 's';

    $records = $model::lists($fields[1], $fields[0]);

    if( !empty( $records ) ){

        foreach( $records as $key => $value ){

            $options[$owner][$value] = $key;
        }
    }


    $options[$owner][''] = $empty;

    return $options;
}
```

And then in the controller you can just use it like:

```
//Get groups
$groups = $this->getList( 'Group', array(
    'name', 'id'
  ));

//Get Project Managers  
$project_managers = $this->getList( 'ProjectManager', array(
  'name', 'id'
 ));
```

The output of the select form control has an optgroup that references the owner of the list or the model rather. How can I remove the optgroup such that its not part of the contents of the dropdown?

Below is the output of the form:

```
<div class="input select">
  <label for="project_manager">Project Manager</label>
  <select name="project_manager_id">
    <optgroup label="projectmanagers">
      <option value="1">Riyaadh</option>
      <option value="2">Luyanda</option>
      <option selected="selected" value="">Select option below</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: The reason you are getting optgroups in your select drop down is you are adding them within your getLists method, on the line,  `$options[$owner][$value] = $key;` The select adds optgroups for each when there are multidimensional arrays within the data passed into the `Form::select()` , the associative key being the label for the group, remove these and there will not be any optgroups. In short just return your `$records` variable and all the optgroups will be gone.

Comment: Hi Matt! Returning just the $records variable on my reusable BaseController function only populates the dropdown list with record IDs.

Comment: Ok then, another way to resolve this would be to change `$options[$owner][$value] = $key;` to this `$options[$value] = $key;`, as said you are adding another level into the array, thus adding the optgroup.

Comment: Thanks Matt. This has resolved my issue. I knew there should be a way of doing this. The idea was to not clutter my controller with 2 lines of code to get model lists thus wanted to create something re-usable. You saved my day.... :-)

Comment: Added as an answer @LuyandaSiko

Answer (score 3):

You are adding another level within your `getLists` method with this line; `$options[$owner][$value] = $key;`, this is what is adding your optgroup, to get rid of this change the line to `$options[$value] = $key;`.

Optionally you can reduce the code of your `getLists` function to the following;

```
protected function getList( $model, array $fields, $empty = 'Select option  below' )
{
    $options = array();

    $owner = strtolower( $model ) . 's';

    $records = $model::lists($fields[1], $fields[0]);

    if( !empty( $records ) ){

        $options = array_flip($records);
    }


    $options[''] = $empty;

    return $options;
}
```

This uses the array_flip method, which exchanges the keys as values and values as keys.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
 $SchoolDetails = GeneralSettingModel::lists('SchoolName', 'id');

or

$SchoolDetails = DB::table('tablename')->lists('SchoolName', 'id');


    {{ Form::select('SchoolName',array(''=>'Select School')+$SchoolDetails,null, array('id'=> 'SchoolName'))}}
```

**Output:**

```
    <select id="SchoolName" name="SchoolName">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select School</option>
<option value="1">test</option>
<option value="2">test355wrew</option>
<option value="3">GOVT</option>
<option value="4">Kumaraguru</option>
<option value="5">valavan</option>
</select>
```

Comment: A point of clarity... Is GeneralSettingModel an object that is provided by Laravel?

Comment: No.we need to create custom model

Answer (score -1):

you can remove using [JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968481/is-there-a-way-to-remove-optgroup-without-destroying-the-code) by adding ID to select

```
 $(function () {
     $("#mySelect").children().remove("optgroup");
 });
```

Comment: Hi Kamlesh! Your hack leaves my dropdown with nothing but the empty string "Select blah blah blah"...

Comment: Just checked it now and it works. I just wonder did it remove everything on my side. I will try to replicate this and see if I did something wrong but the issue I was having is solved.

Comment: The solution to backend code behavior is never frontend code.

Answer (score -3):

As Matt Burrow suggested it turned out that I was creating a multi-dimentional array which is translated to a list with optgroup.

I modified my function to rather exclude the owner which the records belong to. Below is my perfectly working function (excerpt):

```
 ...
 if( !empty( $records ) ){

    foreach( $records as $key => $value ){

       $options[$value] = $key;
    }
 }

 $options[''] = $empty;
 ...
```